# different pip version conflicts how can I solve this

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python3, pip, django

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install django~=1.11.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 984, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 875, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 8.1.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3147, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3131, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3160, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 668, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 681, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 870, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? What's the output of `pip3 --version`, `apt-cache policy python3-pip`, and `which pip3`? How did you install `pip3`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster According to the package version numbers in the question, Himanshu sharma installed the default version of python3-pip (version 8.1.1) in Ubuntu 16.04 and did not subsequently manually upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling pip through python did the trick for me, e.g.:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.1
```

(or whatever version you see in `Requirement.parse('pip==X.Y.Z')`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade pip first:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: **not working**

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: same error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You got the following error message:

```
'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

pip 9.0.1 is the current latest version of pip. To upgrade pip3 to version 9.0.1 run the following command.

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip  
sudo -H pip3 install django==1.11 # latest django long term support release
```

This worked on my system with pip3 9.0.1. The results are shown below. (If these commands don't work, paste the error message into your question.)

```
Installing collected packages: django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.10.5
    Uninstalling Django-1.10.5:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.10.5
Successfully installed django-1.11
```